# Problem with include command and bibtex in beamer [Metropolis theme]

Tags: beamer, bibtex, include, undefined

I have a problem with references in beamer (metropolis theme) and the use of include commands. Indeed, my presentation consists of several files. Each file is included via the include command.

The problem is that when I make a reference from these files, I have a problem of an undefined reference whereas if I make a reference from a frame in the master file, there is no problem.
Do you have an idea ?

Just below the master file (MWE):

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usetheme[subsectionpage=progressbar]{metropolis}
\usepackage{appendixnumberbeamer}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[scale=2]{ccicons}
\usepackage{xspace}
\newcommand{\themename}{\textbf{\textsc{metropolis}}\xspace}

\begin{document}
%  myfile included via include commande
\include{./myfile}   

% reference here works fine
\begin{frame}  
   The reference here works fine \cite{ridge04}
\end{frame}

    \begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{Références}
  \bibliography{./biblio/biblio}
  \bibliographystyle{abbrv}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

myFile.tec looks like this:

```
\section{Contribution}
\begin{frame}
The reference does not work here  \cite{ridge04} !
\end{frame}
```

Comment: Any specific reason to use `\include`? If not, use `\input`.

Comment: Try to rename your file to `myfile.tex`

Comment: @samcarter it's just a typo in my question.

Comment: @FiesAtoS So your real file is names `myfile.tex` and not `myFile.tex`?

Comment: @FiesAtoS Can you test (in another folder so no files will be overwritten) if https://pastebin.com/AWUeDyf2 works for you?

Comment: The problem is solved by changing \include by \input, but I do not know why.   @Phelype Oleinik  put your comment as response so that I can validate it.  samcarter Thank for your help too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution here is to replace the `\include` by `\input`.

The `\input{file}` command is equivalent to copy-pasting the contents of `file` to the place where the `\input` is called.

The `\include{file}` command, on the other hand, does a few other fancies. It does a `\clearpage` before and after including the contents of the file and creates a separate .aux for the included file. [[reference]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246/when-should-i-use-input-vs-include)

Generally `\include` is used when writing something like a book, when you want the sections heads on separate pages. Otherwise `\input` can be used.

(My 2 cents: I always use `\input` and take care of the page breaking manually just to avoid the multiple .aux files).

There is something in your file that breaks the cross referencing for some reason I don't quite understand. It would be necessary more than a *Minimal* Working Example to see what's going on because the code from your MWE works perfectly.

**TL;DR:** The solution is to replace `\include` by `\input` to avoid the multiple .aux files.